# HD webcam for iChat

Tags: compatibility, ichat, webcam, skype

I've seen a couple of Mac compatible HD webcams for sale, but they often come with the caveat of falling back to VGA resolutions when used with any application not supported by the camera manufacturer. So, my question is:

Which webcams can I purchase which will support HD resolutions in all Mac video applications?

Comment: I didn't know that so many things got throttled! Man, that sucks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at "[Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/webcam-communications/webcams/devices/6816)", (STAY AWAY) 
(but I read that various mac users had issues with it, so I investigated.)

I found this on TUAW,(2011-01-04) [Logitech's HD Pro Webcam C910 now ready for Photo Booth, iChat and FaceTime](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/01/04/logitechs-hd-pro-webcam-c910-now-ready-for-photo-booth-ichat-a/) :

> **The software allows integration with
>   iPhoto and iMovie**, and enables the
>   C910 webcam to be used with Skype,
>   Yahoo! Messenger and Gmail Voice and
>   Video Chat.

I really can't help you ... I would hold out for the Logitech ... maybe a updated Driver will fix the issues.

Comment: STAY AWAY? Does that mean that the C910 is not ready for primetime? Or, does this update fix the aforementioned issues?

Comment: yes .. .stay away for now.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this on Mashable and thought about the question :

http://mashable.com/2011/05/24/logitech-c910-review/

Comment: Same old story, supposedly 1080p recording, but only with custom software... I'm beginning to see why Cisco charges 100K for their web conferencing solutions.